# Cut and paste cells counting rows or using array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to cut and paste cells in a spreadsheet that correspond to subtotals. The subtotals are multi-level (2 levels). There are two scenarios that I am trying to work with:

1. identify the subtotals in column B (7 subtotals) and cut and paste to the same row in column D
2. identify the subtotals in column C (24 subtotals) and cut and paste to the same row in column D

Is there any code that can accomplish this? If you have a solution it is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Have you tried right click paste > and paste code not ordinary paste ?

Comment: 1) Is what you're trying to accomplish basically moving those cells (with formulas intact), to new locations, pasting a hard copy of the current result in the new locations, or something else?  2) Why do you need to identify those subtotals?  Can't you just work with the known locations?  Or does that language imply an assumption that this will require a generic macro that finds the subtotals and then deals with them?  Same question about the counting rows and array reference in the title.

Comment: There isn't code to accomplish this. This is unique to you only. You have to write the program (code) yourself. You'd better get started and then when you get stuck, give a try back.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes I want to move those cells and hard copy. This file is dynamic so using known locations is not an option. I mis-spoke in my original question, the cells I want to move are actually "row headers" and not formulas. Yes looking for generic macro that finds the "row header" for each subtotal row and deals with them. I have dealt with row count but only for 1 set of data, this file has multiple sets of data with subtotal rows making row count difficult if even possible.

Comment: I've heard of using arrays to deal with column headers but not sure how to use that kind of function for "row headers" (but they're really not row headers becuz not all rows are titled and "headers" are in col B and C)

Comment: Your requirement is very ambiguous.  Your description could apply to endless things, some simple, some complicated.  It would be easier for people to help if you add an example.

Comment: If I were able to post a file with the data, I would. I agree it would be a lot easier than trying to describe the scenario I am working with.